# Как отключить вспышку у камеры в openCV на C++

Tags: c++, opencv

Делаю снимки через OpenCV на С++. Вспышка часто бывает лишней, мешает. Возможно ее можно отключить через какую-нибудь функцию?

```
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    Mat img;

for (i; i < 2; i++)
    cap.read(img);
    imwrite("cam.png", img);
    cap.release();
```

собственно часть которая делает снимок

Comment: А нельзя ли привести код, при помощи которого делается снимок? Может, если будет код-будет проще подсказать?

Comment: привел.........

Comment: я никгда не сталкивался с использванием OpenCV наа устройствах, на котрых есть вcпышка. Так как в вызве cap.read(img); никакого дполнительного параметра нет, думаю, что для OpenCV вспышка является слишком "низкоуровневым примитивом" и на уровне OpenCV не настраивается. Но так как при делании фото вызывается некая системная функция "сделать фото" - я бы стал копать в сторону того, как поменять дефолтные системные настройки фотоографий до того, как вызывать функцию из OpenCV. Проверить моё предполоожение просто: отключите вручную вспышку. Потом - пробуйте OpenCV.